# How to print collection fields in a list

Tags: flutter, listview

How to print the `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4` in a list?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:grocery_shopping/pages/home/homepage.dart';
import 'package:grocery_shopping/widgets/cart_products.dart';
import 'package:grocery_shopping/widgets/cart_total.dart';

class OrderSuccessful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderSuccessfulState createState() => _OrderSuccessfulState();
}

class _OrderSuccessfulState extends State<OrderSuccessful> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Order Successful")),
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            CartTotal(),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('personalinfo').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                if (!snapshot.hasData){
                  return Text("no value");
                }
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document){
                    return Text(document['field1'] + " " + document['field2'] + " " + document['field3'] + " " + document['field4'], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18));
                  }).toList(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                );
              },
            ),

            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.to(() => CatalogScreen()),
              child: Text('Continue'),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document){
                  print(document['field1']); // print goes here
                  print(document['field2']);
                    return Text(document['field1'] + " " + document['field2'] + " " + document['field3'] + " " + document['field4'], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18));
                  }).toList(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                );
```

// Try this

Comment: this just prints on the console but not the app